# Docker container to container command execution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql-workbench, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm which I start using the stack deploy command like so:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml test
```

Say two of the containers are A and B, B contains a shell script launch.sh, which needs to be executed from a program running in A. Something like the way ssh works.
I did find a couple of solutions

1. enable ssh in both the containers and export their keys and all that .
2. write a script in B which checks for a flag in some DB and this flag is updated by A.

Honestly, solution A does not seem feasible to me at all. I am tilting towards B but I was wondering if Docker provides some sort of command for this. I know there is exec, but how do I use that for container-to-container  execution, especially since the names of the containers are variable?

Comment: See https://forums.docker.com/t/execute-command-from-a-container-to-another-container/19492

Comment: Thanks that helped .It did make me realize that option 2 is still the best way for me ,